# XAML Stop List Box Text Style Changing on Defocus

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, styles

I have an issue with a .NET 4 XAML program which contains a ListBox.
When a the list box looses focus the text turns to grey rather than the set white colour. The background did do this but I resolved that with

```
    <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#376807" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#487918" />
    </Style.Resources>
```

I have tried several methods of resolving this including

```
    <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#444444" />
            </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
```

But not have been successful...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried modifying the default control template?

Comment: @Gabe I have not as my understanding was this would change all list boxes. I only want this applied to this instance of a list box.

Comment: Hi, Did you try to use expression blend? I can help you to solve this quickly if you have it :)

Comment: @AllanChua said try to use expression blend to style your controls, it is easy and effective, you can create styles and change properties on it to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm happy to use any method, I have got expression blend installed, don't really use it however.

Answer (score 2):

**OK I have edited my code. Just check if this satisfies your need, if not then please revert.**

The following has been tried with some dummy data in the listbox and it works. I hope this is what you were looking for, if not, then please clarify some more.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Green" Foreground="White" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="dummyList" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
</ListBox>
<Button Height="31" Width="61" Content="Click"/>
    <ListBox Name="listBox2" Height="100" Width="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBoxItem Content="XX" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="YY" />
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is how that looks when the control has focus... https://picasaweb.google.com/102030574521780088003/October102011#5661803215680396738

Heres how it looks when it dosnt..e.g. click out the window https://picasaweb.google.com/102030574521780088003/October102011#5661803215487955234

Comment: @Eddie, why isn't it working? Let me know what was the issue, I will be glad to help out.